# Selenium WebDriver - Select - GETOPTIONS method

Tags: java, selenium

In below code using getoptions method in select, I am fetching all the webelements for date drop-down and printing it using for loop

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
WebElement select_date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='day']"));
Select dselect = new Select(select_date);

List<WebElement> list_options = dselect.getOptions();
System.out.println(list_options.size());

for (int i=0;i<list_options.size();i++) {
System.out.println(list_options.get(i));
}
```

Size of list_options(WebElement) is 32.

If we observe it has printed the same address 32 times

```
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (53f97259-e77a-4ac9-a93f-58045437fff1)] -> xpath: //select[@id='day']]] -> tag name: option]
```

[image: List of dates]

Question
Even though size of list_options(WebElement) is 32. Why it printed the same address 32 times?

Why it didn't print 32 unique address.

Answer (score 0):

It prints the same 32 times because that is the UUID of the `FirefoxDriver` sessionID not the `WebElement`. See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/37088bb0979bc6e5b6f03b66eb023d6af1c400ac/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java#L994

If you want the unique ID of the WebElement, you'll have to call `getId()` on it

Comment: `System.out.println(list_options.get(i).getId());`